Wordpress Post Query Using Custom native MySQL like St_Distance_Sphere
Is there a way to query posts for "the loop". But include some filter on the results based on a mySQL Function like St_Distance_Sphere? Or convert a wpdb->query into a form similar to "the loop?"
I have wordpress coordinates stored in the wordpress database. I loop through the Posts throughout my templates and am hoping to use the St_Distance_Sphere function on this query to filter the posts. This example SQL is just something I pulled to demonstrate St_Distance_Sphere.
    select
  address_id
from
  geo_data
where
  (
    ST_Distance_Sphere(
      point(longitude, latitude),      -- Columns on the geo_data table
      point(-97.745363, 30.324014)     -- Fixed reference point
    ) *.000621371192
  ) <= 1;    

I am hoping to somehow add this where clause to my existing post query to include it in a template similar to adding args to a wordpress post query for "the loop".

You haven't supplied enough information to answer the question. What's the structure of the geo_data table and relationship to wp_posts?

I am querying a ACF database with coordinates. I loop through the ACF Posts throughout my templates and am hoping to to use the St_Distance_Sphere function on this query.
The example SQL is just something I pulled to demonstate St_Distance_Sphere.

ACF is a third party plugin and thus off topic for this Stack. You can find information on how to query ACF fields here: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/query-posts-custom-fields/ and how to incorporate custom SQL in the WP loop here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Displaying_Posts_Using_a_Custom_Select_Query

My question wasn't off topic until I mentioned ACF I wasn't asking how to query ACF fields, your article answers my questions so thank you.

you could query for post IDs via WPDB then feed those IDs into the loop, otherwise you'r messing with SQL filters. Note though that using this on the post meta table will be very expensive and slow, you will want to avoid it if your sites posts table has more than double digits
